# How to use Socket.IO for iOS client and Python server?

Tags: python, ios, swift, sockets, socket.io

Honestly, my head is killing me with this.

I just want to simply connect both a python script (on a raspberry pi) to my iOS swift app. Nothing is working apart from an apparent 'connection' on the python side (which should be acting as the server. I am using [this](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) repo for my socket.io swift client, and [this](https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html#) for my python socket.io server.

I've tried both code examples on both of their documentations, nothing is happening, no data is being shared, the python server script seems to think there's a connection when I run the app, but the app thinks different. Emitting messages aren't working, callbacks/acknowledgements aren't working either, surely I'm doing something wrong?

I've successfully connected this python script to my Node.js driven backend without a problem and it works flawlessly.

This is my Swift iOS client code:

```
let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://\(hubIP ?? "0.0.0.0"):8080")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
let socket = manager.defaultSocket
            
socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) {data, ack in
        print("socket connected")
}
            
socket.on("callback") {data, ack in 
        print(data)
}
               
socket.connect()
```

And this is my python (server) side code:

```
@sio.event 
async def connect(sid, environ):
    print('Connection', sid)
    await sio.emit('callback', "testing")

@sio.event
def disconnect(sid):
    print('Disconnection')

@sio.event
def update(data):
    print(data)
```

Now, when I do run my app, in the python shell, this does print:

```
Connection 9a39ca47581a4a4fa13a6ab0ae49d2c9
```

Which is something, however the `socket.on(clientEvent: .connect)` does not fire on the iOS side - from what I can see.

This is my console within Xcode, when I enable debugging:

```
2020-08-31 21:09:37.633585+0100 [46528:929263] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: connect
2020-08-31 21:09:37.633846+0100 [46528:929263] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Adding handler for event: callback
2020-08-31 21:09:37.634416+0100 [46528:929263] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: statusChange with data: [connecting, 2]
2020-08-31 21:09:37.634731+0100 [46528:929263] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Joining namespace /
2020-08-31 21:09:37.634935+0100 [46528:929263] LOG SocketManager: Tried connecting socket when engine isn't open. Connecting
2020-08-31 21:09:37.635093+0100 [46528:929263] LOG SocketManager: Adding engine
2020-08-31 21:09:37.636300+0100 [46528:929263] LOG SocketManager: Manager is being released
2020-08-31 21:09:37.636367+0100 [46528:929411] LOG SocketEngine: Starting engine. Server: http://192.168.0.33:8080
2020-08-31 21:09:37.636523+0100 [46528:929411] LOG SocketEngine: Handshaking
2020-08-31 21:09:37.636528+0100 [46528:929263] LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Client is being released
2020-08-31 21:09:37.637237+0100 [46528:929411] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET http://192.168.0.33:8080/socket.io/?transport=polling&b64=1
2020-08-31 21:09:37.677613+0100 [46528:929414] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got polling response
2020-08-31 21:09:37.677835+0100 [46528:929414] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Got poll message: 109:0{"sid":"6cf19e66c3e34fe09b59cd452f6ec49a","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingTimeout":60000,"pingInterval":25000}24:42["callback","testing"]2:40
2020-08-31 21:09:37.678339+0100 [46528:929414] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 0{"sid":"6cf19e66c3e34fe09b59cd452f6ec49a","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingTimeout":60000,"pingInterval":25000}
2020-08-31 21:09:37.683767+0100 centreCore[46528:929414] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 42["callback","testing"]
2020-08-31 21:09:37.683958+0100 [46528:929414] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 40
2020-08-31 21:09:37.684428+0100 [46528:929414] LOG SocketEngine: Writing poll:  has data: false
2020-08-31 21:09:37.685011+0100 [46528:929414] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Sending poll:  as type: 2
2020-08-31 21:09:37.685843+0100 [46528:929414] LOG SocketEnginePolling: Created POST string: 1:2
2020-08-31 21:09:37.686503+0100 [46528:929414] LOG SocketEnginePolling: POSTing
2020-08-31 21:09:37.687064+0100 [46528:929414] LOG SocketEngine: Engine is being released
```

I can see with these lines, as I am writing this that it does receive messages, just just nothing with them, via these lines from above:

```
109:0{"sid":"6cf19e66c3e34fe09b59cd452f6ec49a","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingTimeout":60000,"pingInterval":25000}24:42["callback","testing"]2:40
2020-08-31 21:09:37.678339+0100 [46528:929414] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 0{"sid":"6cf19e66c3e34fe09b59cd452f6ec49a","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingTimeout":60000,"pingInterval":25000}
2020-08-31 21:09:37.683767+0100 [46528:929414] LOG SocketEngine: Got message: 42["callback","testing"]
```

I can see the correct Sid for the socket being displayed, and the callback function with the data 'testing' being printed, but why is nothing happening code wise? I just need this first, let alone callbacks and ack?

Comment: Could you update your server side code? I think something is missing (socket initialization)

Comment: @pazitos10 server-side code? I provided all the code that is relevant to this question above, I explained that I used socketIO for my python script to talk to my backend just to explain I know what I'm doing, that part has nothing to do with this question :)

Comment: My bad. I did not read that your client is connecting succesfully.

Comment: @pazitos10 Yeah, it's apparently connecting, but nothing else is happening after it?